# How to change data types of multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of multiple data frames.

```
files_list <- list(data_04, data_05, data_06, data_07, data_08, data_09, data_010, data_011,
                   data_012, data_013, data_015, data_016, data_017, data_018)
```

How do i change the data types of each column so that they match through data frames. All of the data frames have the same columns and column names.
I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
for (i in files_list) {
  i %>%
  mutate(ride_id = as.character(ride_id)) %>%
  mutate(rideable_type = as.character(rideable_type)) %>%
  mutate(started_at = as_datetime(started_at)) %>%
  mutate(ended_at = as_datetime(ended_at)) %>%
  mutate(start_station_name = as.character(start_station_name)) %>%
  mutate(start_station_id = as.integer(start_station_id)) %>%
  mutate(end_station_name = as.character(end_station_name)) %>%
  mutate(end_station_id = as.integer(end_station_id)) %>%
  mutate(start_lat = as.numeric(start_lat)) %>%
  mutate(start_lng = as.numeric(start_lng)) %>%
  mutate(end_lat = as.numeric(end_lat)) %>%
  mutate(end_lng = as.numeric(end_lng)) %>%
  mutate(member_casual = as.character(member_casual))
}
```

Comment: In your code you do not update the data frames. Have you tried inside the `for` loop `i <- i %>% ...` with ... equal as you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

Try this shorter version of Tob's code: It will depend how date columns are saved in df!

```
EditDataFunction <- function(data){
    clean_data <- data %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
    
    return(clean_data)
}

clean_list <- lapply(files_list, EditDataFunction)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function and then use `lapply()` on the list.

The below should work but I can't be sure since I don't know what the data looks like.

```
EditDataFunction <- function(data){
  clean_data <- data %>% 
    mutate(ride_id = as.character(ride_id)) %>%
    mutate(rideable_type = as.character(rideable_type)) %>%
    mutate(started_at = as_datetime(started_at)) %>%
    mutate(ended_at = as_datetime(ended_at)) %>%
    mutate(start_station_name = as.character(start_station_name)) %>%
    mutate(start_station_id = as.integer(start_station_id)) %>%
    mutate(end_station_name = as.character(end_station_name)) %>%
    mutate(end_station_id = as.integer(end_station_id)) %>%
    mutate(start_lat = as.numeric(start_lat)) %>%
    mutate(start_lng = as.numeric(start_lng)) %>%
    mutate(end_lat = as.numeric(end_lat)) %>%
    mutate(end_lng = as.numeric(end_lng)) %>%
    mutate(member_casual = as.character(member_casual))
  
  return(clean_data)
  
}

clean_list <- lapply(files_list, EditDataFunction)
```

Then if you need to bind them all together you could use `data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: About the last paragraph: You can also use the base version: `do.call(rbind, clean_list)`